# Docker: kitematic timeout to get container

Tags: docker, kitematic

I am trying to learn docker so i installed official docker application from it's site and after installing i installed kitematic.I am using windows 10:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 19.03.1
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc version: 425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.9.184-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 1.952GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: VABX:P63L:ONMD:575Z:O4HT:WEZJ:RBNK:VB3G:4DC7:LI7T:YGX6:E4JL
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 29
  Goroutines: 44
  System Time: 2019-08-21T11:22:46.4753036Z
  EventsListeners: 2
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine

PS D:\Software\Windows\Docker\Kitematic-Windows>
```

After running kitamatic and search `busybox` and clicked on `create` after a few second i got this error:

`(HTTP code 500) server error - Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: read udp 192.168.65.3:57485->192.168.65.1:53: i/o timeout`

to test i used terminal to create container :

```
PS D:\Software\Windows\Docker\Kitematic-Windows> docker run busybox
Unable to find image 'busybox:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/busybox/manifests/latest: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?account=731364&scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fbusybox%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: dial tcp: lookup auth.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: read udp 192.168.65.3:53973->192.168.65.1:53: i/o timeout.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
PS D:\Software\Windows\Docker\Kitematic-Windows>
```

What's happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Your machine is using 192.168.65.1 as DNS server to resolve the IP for registry-1.docker.io.

In a lot of places, it's suggested to go in the settings and change the DNS from Automatic to Fixed: 8.8.8.8

Comment: That's your mean of setting is docker client or network interface?@Stefano

Comment: it should be in the docker client. Anyway I also found this blog that might be useful: https://kumarvikram.com/docker-io-timeout-error-resolved-windows/

Comment: I am sure i do this trick before but the problem still was happen but i'll try tomorrow again and i will announce you @Stefano

Comment: I changed but i got `(HTTP code 500) server error - Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: read udp 192.168.65.3:53856->192.168.65.1:53: i/o timeout` @Stefano

Comment: In company that i work to connect to internet we have to use VPN so i think i got error for that reason! Is there any trick to solve this problem?@Stefano

Comment: Check if you're using a proxy or something similar. Check this: https://forums.docker.com/t/error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2/23741/13